# Error when executing VBA code when wrong Excel tab is open

Tags: vba

My VBA code utilizes two Excel spreadsheets. It gets data from one (Tab1) and writes results to the other tab (Tab2). However, when I launch the code while Tab2 is open, VBA is giving me "Application defined or Object Defined error". Code works find when I am on Tab1.  Below is the line of code where it chokes:

```
Set YE_last = Forecast.Range(Cells(YE_forecast.Row + 1, YE_forecast.Column + i - 1), Cells(YE_forecast.Row + 1, YE_forecast.Column + i - 1))
```

Can you help please!

Answer (score 0):

`Cells` without a worksheet object qualifier, implicitly refers to whatever the `ActiveSheet` is (if you're in a standard code module). If you're in a worksheet's code-behind module, then unqualified `Cells` calls are basically doing `Me.Cells`, i.e. they're referring to *that* worksheet.

Solution is to qualify everything with the sheet object you're working with:

```
Set YE_last = Forecast.Range(Forecast.Cells(YE_forecast.Row + 1, YE_forecast.Column + i - 1), Forecast.Cells(YE_forecast.Row + 1, YE_forecast.Column + i - 1))
```

A `With` block can simplify this:

```
With Forecast
    Set YE_last = .Range(.Cells(YE_forecast.Row + 1, YE_forecast.Column + i - 1), .Cells(YE_forecast.Row + 1, YE_forecast.Column + i - 1))
End With
```